# how to get singleton instance in another class

Tags: c#

I want to get the Lazy instance in another class the problem is that the T type is only set in the main class

the first class where the instance is is this:

```
public class singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private readonly static Lazy<T> val = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());
    public static T instance { get { return val.Value; } }

    public int UserID {get;set;} 
}
```

now I have a other class for all user datas

```
public class User
{ 
    public string Name()
    {
        return data.GetUserFromID(singleton.instance.UserID)
    }
}
```

the singleton is not working because I need the Argument but the T is only in the main class

```
public class main : singleton<main>
{
    public main()
    {
        UserID = 5; 
    }
}
```

EDIT

how do I get the ID from the singleton class inside another class like this
singleton file

```
   public class singleton<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        private readonly static Lazy<T> val = new Lazy<T>(() => new T());
        public static T instance { get { return val.Value; } }

        public int UserID {get;set;} 

        private singleton() {
         Datas.UserID = UserID;
        }    
}
```

another file

```
public class Datas {
      public static int UserID {get;set;} 
}
```

Comment: `main` has a public constructor so it's not a singleton.

Comment: I only want know how I get this `singleton.instance.UserID`

Comment: Side note: your naming is inconsistent. Use UpperCamelCase for all classes, not only User.

Comment: Re your bottom code, your "singleton" will **always** result in an object instance of type `singleton` and not say `main`.  I don't think you understand how _inheritence_ works.

Comment: @MickyD Yeah I m really new in that I watched some youtube videos

Answer (score 0):

> the singleton is not working because I need the Argument but the T is only in the main class

All you need do is change your code from:

```
public class User { 
 public string Name() {
  return data.GetUserFromID(singleton.instance.UserID)
 }
}
```

...to specifying the generic type argument:

```
public class User 
{ 
    public string Name()
    {
        var m = singleton<main>.instance;
        Console.WriteLine($"Inside User.Name, m.UserId = {m.UserID}");
        return "todo";
    }
}
```

This is required because your client code is accessing the generic base directly.  Had you encapsulated it into a factory manager or similar, clients would not need to specify the type.

Here is a little test harness

```
private void Run()
{
    var x = singleton<main>.instance;
    Console.WriteLine($"x.UserId = {x.UserID}");

    var y = singleton<main>.instance;
    Console.WriteLine($"y.UserId = {y.UserID}");

    x.UserID++;
    Console.WriteLine($"x.UserId = {x.UserID}");
    Console.WriteLine($"y.UserId = {y.UserID}");

    var user = new User();
    Console.WriteLine($"User.Name = {user.Name()}");

    var mp = MissPiggy.Instance;
}
```

Which produces the following results.  Note how changing properies on two different variables modifies the same singleton.

[image]

There are a few problems too with how you are implementing singletons.  A singleton class should have a `private` constructor and it should be the one managing lifetimes and not a secondary class.

e.g.

```
public sealed class MissPiggy
{
    private static Lazy<MissPiggy> _instance = new Lazy<MissPiggy>(() => new MissPiggy());

    private MissPiggy()
    {

    }

    public static MissPiggy Instance
    {
        get { return _instance.Value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanxs for your answer, but the main class is not in the dll file I cant use in the user class `singleton<main>`

Comment: @VanessaHirse then it sounds like you are getting into circular dependency issues.  Consider using abstrations and decouple your contracts from implementation. Define a _contracts_ library that contains nothing but `interface` definitions that all projects use and create another library that holds the actual implementation.  Only core code should refer to the implementation dll

Comment: @VanessaHirse Your "singleton" will **always** result in the type being an object of type `singleton` and not say `main`.  I don't think you understand how _inheritence_ works.

Comment: I have edited my post again maybe this could help now

Comment: @VanessaHirse Pretty sure I've already answered that. You keep editing your question between the two examples of what is essentially a generic which isn't generic at all and one that is but isn't particularly useful.  Such edits can possibly invalidate existing answers

Answer (score 0):

`singleton<t>` is a generic type - you can't refer to it without a generic type parameter.

Under the hood, it's actually generating new types.

So when you do this:

```
var mainSingleton = singleton<main>.instance;
```

It's actually creating a new type which looks like this:

```
public class NewGenericTypeWithWeirdName
{
    private readonly static Lazy<main> val = new Lazy<main>(() => new main());
    public static main instance { get { return val.Value; } }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

...and if you declare `var otherSingleton = singleton<SomethingElse>.instance;` then it does the same thing - it creates another type, just like above, except `T` is replaced with `SomethingElse`.

That's why you can't do this:

```
singleton.instance.UserID
```

Because the compiler doesn't know which type you're referring to. Is it the type it generated for `singleton<main>`, or is it the type generated for `singleton<SomethingElse>`? They're actually different types, which means the static properties - including `UserID`, will be different for each of them.

You could do this:

```
return data.GetUserFromID(singleton<main>.instance.UserID);
                                   ^^^^^^
```

...because now you're telling it the actual type - it's `singleton<main>`.

---

Just to clarify, unless the class has a `private` constructor and no non-private constructors, it isn't a singleton.

You can do this:

```
var mainSingleton = singleton<main>.instance;
```

and it will always return the same instance of `main`.

But you can also do this:

```
var m1 = new singleton<main>();
var m2 = new singleton<main>();
```

You can create multiple instances, so it's not a singleton. To fix this, add a private constructor to `singleton`:

private singleton() {}

Now the constructor can only be called from within the class. That means the only way to get an instance is to call `instance`. Every time you do that you'll get the same instance, so now it really is a singleton.

Comment: thanxs for your answer I have edited my post when I remove the `<T> where T : class, new()` I can use `singleton.instance.UserID` but the UserID is empty

Comment: That's because `main` sets the `UserID` property, but `singleton` doesn't.  Also, `main` isn't a singleton. It has a public constructor. There's nothing to prevent creating multiple instances of it.

Comment: how can I make that the singleton sets the userID without the <T>

Comment: You can't. Because `singleton<T>` is a generic type, there's no such thing as `singleton` without the `T`. And every time you use `singleton<T>` with a different type for `T`, it creates a different type. So `singleton<main>.instance` and `singleton<SomethingElse>`.instance` are two different objects. They could have different UserIDs. So if you set the UserID without the `T`, which UserID would you be setting?

Comment: It still leads back to the same question - you want to get the `UserID` from `singleton.instance` - but `singleton<what>.instance`? There's no getting around that. Perhaps a good first step would be to create the singleton without any generic arguments. Just create the singleton for one type.

Comment: the singleton comes from `singleton<main>.instance` I cant use `singleton.instance.UserID` so I have then the static class Datas and Is it not possible to set Datas.UserID from the singleton<main>.instance.UserID

Comment: This isn't going to sound helpful, but it's really meant to be helpful. In order for any of this to make sense and not drive you insane, I think a first step is to try to do anything and everything you're trying to do without `static` anything and without singletons. Whether we've been doing this a short time or a long time, static values and shared classes can make code much harder to understand. 20% is learning to understand it. 80% is avoiding doing things that make it harder to understand in the first place.